# After using max, how do i know which variable had the maximum value in python?

Tags: python, max

I have some variable inside of a for loop and I have to find the highest value of them all with the name of the variable that has the highest value.

I have used:

```
highest_value = max(a,b,c,d,e)
return highest value
```

it gives me the correct answer but I am not able to recognize which one of the variables had the highest value.

Here is the actual code:

```
def highest_area(self):
        southeast = 0
        southwest = 0
        northeast = 0
        northwest = 0
        others = 0
    
    for i in self.patient_region:
        if i=="southeast":
            southeast += 1
        elif i=="southwest":
            southwest += 1
        elif i=="northeast":
            northeast+=1
        elif i=="northwest":
            northwest+=1
        else:
            others+=1
    highest = max(southeast,southwest,northeast,northwest,others)
    return highest
```

How can I get the name of the highest value by using any built-in function?

Comment: Your problem will be better solved with a dictionary with the keys like `'southeast', 'southwest'` etc.

Comment: So I should make a dictionary and assign the values to the keys and then print the whole dictionary to know which is the highest? oh I never thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary instead of multiple variables to do this. You would use the variable names as the dictionary's keys, and the variable's values would be the values in the dictionary. For example, consider the folllowing code:

```
myDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
print(max(myDict, key=myDict.get))
```

It would output

```
'c'
```

Which is the name of the highest key in the dictionary.

So for your code, implementing this would look like:

```
directions = {
        'southeast' : 1,
        'southwest' : 2,
        'northeast' : 3,
        'northwest' : 4,
        'others' : 5
        }

max_direction = max(directions, key=directions.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = self.patient_region
print(max(set(a), key = a.count))
```

Comment: Similarly than your previous answer, this one appeared on Low Quality Review queue. You are encouraged to add more information in answer than only the code, otherwise you are in a risk of having the answer removed. It is also a good practice to always explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it's the best solution, but:

```
def highest_area(self):
    southeast = 0
    southwest = 0
    northeast = 0
    northwest = 0
    others = 0
    
    for i in self.patient_region:
        if i=="southeast":
            southeast += 1
        elif i=="southwest":
            southwest += 1
        elif i=="northeast":
            northeast+=1
        elif i=="northwest":
            northwest+=1
        else:
            others+=1
    highest = max((southeast, "southeast"), (southwest, "southwest"), (northeast, "northeast"), (northwest, "northwest"),(others, "others"), key=lambda t: t[0])
    return highest[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary to store the variables instead.

Here's your code - simplified:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def highest_area(self):
        directions = dict(
          southeast = 0
          southwest = 0
          northeast = 0
          northwest = 0
        )
        others = 0
    
    for i in self.patient_region:
        if i in directions:
            directions[i] += 1
        else:
            others += 1
    directions['others'] = others
    # highest_dir has the key, while highest_val has the corresponding value
    highest_dir, highest_val = max(directions.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return highest_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max` function won't give you this information, but the following using the `Counter` and `itemgetter` builtins from the Python standard library will work:

```py
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

def highest_area(self):
    counts = Counter(self.patient_region)
    max_direction, max_value = max(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return #whatever you want to return
```

A `Counter` is a dictionary which defaults to containing 0 if you check for a key which isn't present. It behaves as follows:

```py
c = Counter()
print(c) # "Counter()"
c['northwest'] += 1
print(c) # Counter({'northwest': 1})
```

The `itemgetter` bit just tells max to use the second element of the (key, count) tuple to select the maximum.

This is only missing the "other" category from your code, so you can just check if `max_direction` is one of the four directions you expect.